# Как поменять прозрачность панели задач и прочих меню средствами Windows 11?

Tags: windows, стилизация, windows-11

1. В каком файле находится ресурс новой иконки меню пуск?
2. Какой ресурс отвечает за цвет панели задач windows 11?
3. Какой ресурс отвечает за прозрачность панели задач и окон?

Пока начал просматривать .theme и .msstyles файлы, но там есть ресурс иконки старого меню пуск, где же нового?

Comment: Не, главное на кнопочку закрыть мы нажать можем, а как подсказать так никто не знает... Для Windows 10 ресурсы я знаю где, а вот где ресурсы новой панели задач?

Comment: Попробуйте описать задачу подробнее и проще. Что за "ресурсы" вы имеете ввиду? Какая у вас конечная цель?

Comment: Задача: поставить прозрачность панели задач и прочих меню средствами Windows. Сторонние решения не рассматриваю, так как они жрут память. Старые варианты из Windows 10 не работают, их выпилили...